# imagemagick pixel color extraction (force RGB)

Tags: imagemagick

I'm using imagemagick to extract a pixel color @ some `x,y` coordinate in a jpeg image.

The output most of the time is `srgb(R,G,B)` but in some cases it returns `grey##`.

Since I'll need the plain RGB numbers for a calculation, `grey##` is not a good value.

Is it possible to always get RGB values from imagemagick?

The command:

`magick image.jpg -format "%[pixel:p{110,246}]" info:-`

Comment: Is this version-dependent? I'm using the ImageMagick that comes with Mint 20.1 called identify-im6.q16hdri and there is no 'magick' command. 'identify' with those arguments just prints the normal identify output and then hangs. What is that "info:-" on the end doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is compute each color channel separately in ImageMagick fx: computation.

```
magick image.jpg[1x1+110+245] -format "%[fx:round(255*u.r)],%[fx:round(255*u.g)],%[fx:round(255*u.b)]" info:
```

That will produce for example:

[image]

```
magick lena.jpg[1x1+110+245] -format "%[fx:round(255*u.r)],%[fx:round(255*u.g)],%[fx:round(255*u.b)]" info:
```

208,90,88

If you want to include rgb(), then do

```
magick image.jpg[1x1+110+245] -format "rgb(%[fx:round(255*u.r)],%[fx:round(255*u.g)],%[fx:round(255*u.b)])" info:
```

```
magick lena.jpg[1x1+110+245] -format "rgb(%[fx:round(255*u.r)],%[fx:round(255*u.g)],%[fx:round(255*u.b)])" info:
```

rgb(208,90,88)

ADDITION:

If you want multiple pixels returned, then you can do the following:

```
magick lena.jpg -format "rgb(%[fx:round(255*u.p{10,10}.r)],%[fx:round(255*u.p{10,10}.g)],%[fx:round(255*u.p{10,10}.b)]) rgb(%[fx:round(255*u.p{100,100}.r)],%[fx:round(255*u.p{100,100}.g)],%[fx:round(255*u.p{100,100}.b)])\n" info:
```

rgb(226,130,106) rgb(131,46,85)

Comment: Looks good, but what if I want to get 2 pixels? `image.jpg[1x1+110+245]` Is it possible to get 2 pixels in this brackets? For example: `%[pixel:p{847,988}] %[pixel:p{400,300}]" info:`

Comment: You can do that if you put both expressions in the same set of double quotes as for example: `magick lena.jpg -format "%[pixel:u.p{10,10}]  %[pixel:u.p{100,100}]\n" info:` and the result will be:
srgb(226,130,106)  srgb(131,46,85)

Comment: I've made some tests and `-format "%[pixel:u.p{10,10}] %[pixel:u.p{100,100}]\n"` still gives me `grey##`

Comment: The image is color, but if the pixel happens to be grey, imagemagick will give me `grey##` instead of the `srgb()`

Comment: See my ADDITION in my answer.