# Command-line program to grab the RGB of a single pixel without using the mouse?

Tags: image-processing, command-line

I have a directory of 1-pixel (ie 1x1) images and I'd like to get the RGB value of the pixel from each one.

The grabc utility is interesting, but you have to use the mouse, which defeats the objective.

There appears to be a flavour of ImageMagick with arguments to do this, but it is obviously different to the one I have, as there is no 'magick' command, and 'identify' hangs with those arguments (see my comment at [imagemagick pixel color extraction (force RGB)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62053408/imagemagick-pixel-color-extraction-force-rgb)).

Is there some rgbget type of utility that I can run over all the files and output the values to std.out?

Comment: Stack Overflow site is about programming. In case you are looking for a Python solution, the solution is going to be simple. In case you are looking for a tool, you better ask in Super User site.

Comment: I wanted to use this in a script, so in that case it's programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Unix syntax, you can write a for loop over each image in your directory and get the rgb values as follows:

```
cd to directory
for img in *; do
convert "$img" -format "%[pixel:u.p{0,0}]\n" info:
done
```

Comment: That is exactly what I have been trying to do, but the site I referenced, which had the IM format example, assumes some kind of wrapper round IM, and when I tried it with 'identify' it just hung. Never occurred to me to use convert instead...duh. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The answer turns out to be:

```
convert filename.png -format "$COLOUR,%[fx:u.r],%[fx:u.g],%[fx:u.b];\%\n" info: >filename.rgb
```

or, if you want the integer form:

```
convert filename.png -format "$f %[fx:round(255*u.r)],%[fx:round(255*u.g)],%[fx:round(255*u.b)]\n" info: >filename.rgb
```